# How to run a frozen graph in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to run a frozen graph in tensorflow 2.0?.

Observing below error while creating session.

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
   output_data = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: test_images})
```

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

The complete code can be found here.
[Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LMIfvXEIjyAqkOUuBIT1jgw37nJLa7XF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a session class part of "tensorflow.python.client" could run the frozen graph with this session.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import session
with session.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
   output_data = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: test_images})
```

Updated coLab Notebook with this